# Error when loading custom modules in Julia project environment

Tags: julia

I want to create Julia environment in a similar way to a conda environment. However, creating a `Project.toml` with the necessary packages means I am unable to use local/custom modules. I have a basic project structure

```sh
- julia_test
    - MyModule.jl
    - main.jl
```

where `MyModule.jl`

```
module MyModule
function f(a, b)
        return (a+b)^2
end
end
```

and `main.jl`

```
using Distributions

using MyModule

function main()
        a = Normal()
        b = rand(a, 2)
        c = MyModule.f(b[1], b[2])
end

main()
```

Finally set the required environment variable

```sh
export JULIA_LOAD_PATH="~/julia_test:$JULIA_LOAD_PATH"
```

and everything runs fine. However adding a `Project.toml`

```
[deps]
Distributions = "31c24e10-a181-5473-b8eb-7969acd0382f"
```

results in a error when running `main.jl`

```sh
ERROR: LoadError: ArgumentError: Package MyModule not found in current path:
- Run `import Pkg; Pkg.add("MyModule")` to install the MyModule package.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Julia does not have such powerful "package discovery" as python so you need to be more precise when working with package manager.
You can include the module by using

```
include("MyModule.jl")
```

instead of

```
import MyModule
```

where the `"MyModule.jl"` is relative path to the `main.jl`, and that will work.

The thing to notice here is that this is not utilizing the package manager, the `include` function is just spicy copy-paste.

If you wanted to use it as `import MyModule` or `using MyModule` instead of the include, you would need to make a package from `MyModule`. Contrarily to python, Julia does not discover all modules in `JULIA_LOAD_PATH` in same manner as python discovers them in `PYTHONPATH`. The discovery works for packages, not modules.

In order to wrap the `MyModule` into package, you can generate the skeleton using `] generate MyModule` which will generate the following structure (assuming you run it in `julia_test`)

```
- julia_test
  - MyModule (this is generated)
    - src
      - MyModule.jl
    - Project.toml
  - MyModule.jl (this is here from earlier)
  - main.jl (this is here from earlier)
```

and if you move the `julia_test/MyModule.jl` to `julia_test/MyModule/src/MyModule.jl`, then you are able to run `] dev MyModule` which will add it as development dependency (all changes in `MyModule` will be reflected similarily to `pip install -e <package>`).

Then you can call `using MyModule` or `import MyModule` and it will work. You should see in `julia_test/Manifest.toml` the `MyModule` and its relative path.

In order to add it using `] add MyModule` as a package instead of `dev`, the `MyModule` would need to be a git repo, because julia allows adding only git repos as packages (`dev` is the exception).

Also, to make it work, you don't need to modify the `JULIA_LOAD_PATH`, because the `MyModule` in `] dev MyModule` is the relative path from your working directory.

Comment: I find this quite unsatisfactory as it precludes the easy `using MyModule: f`. Is there no way around this? I am surprised that `JULIA_LOAD_PATH` cannot be used in a similar manner to `PYTHONPATH`.

Comment: Yes, you're right, I'll elaborate in the answer.